# Unable to solve a Python error message

Tags: python

**The code is from K. Pollari-Malmi's lecture notes for the course "Introduction to Programming":**

```
def main():
    print "Ohjelma laskee asuntolainan kuukausierat." 
    rivi = raw_input("Anna lainasumma: ") 
    lainasumma = float(rivi) 
    rivi = raw_input("Anna laina-aika vuosina: ") 
    laina_aika = int(rivi) 
    if laina_aika < 1: 
        print "liian lyhyt laina-aika" 
    else: 
        kk_lkm = 12 * laina_aika 
        rivi = raw_input("Anna korkoprosentti: ") 
        korko = float(rivi) 
        lyhennys = lainasumma / kk_lkm 
        paaoma = lainasumma 
        i = 0 
        print " lyhennys korko yhteensa" 
        while i < kk_lkm: 
            i = i + 1 
            korkoera = korko / 1200.0 * paaoma 
            paaoma = paaoma - lyhennys 
            kuukausiera = korkoera + lyhennys 
            print "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % \         # mistake probably here
                (i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera) 
main()
```

I get the syntax error

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

**How can you solve the error message?**

Comment: @Masi: Please read: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several answers already gave you the crux of your problem, but I want to make a plug for my favorite way to get logical line continuation in Python, when feasible:

```
print "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % (         # no mistake here
            i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera)
```

i.e., instead of using extra parentheses as some answers advise, you can take advantage of any parenthesis you already naturally happen to have -- that will tell Python that you need logical line continuation, too;-)

Comment: @Alex: Thank you for your answer! I see that your way is the best one.

Comment: =/ i don't like it. The lone paren on the first line bother me.

Comment: Careful with this, however. It'll break if the code gets used in a Python 3.0 implementation-- given the new print syntax. Not so much an issue to you now, just something to be conscious of.

Comment: @mettadore: Could you give an example how we use the print in Python 3.1 for the same purpose? -- I am reading the docs at http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print

Comment: The 2to3 code conversion tool that comes with Python 2.6 and Python 3 has no trouble converting Python 2's print stataments into Python 3 print function calls (in this case, it will insert the parentheses that the print function needs and the print statement doesn't).

Comment: @Triptych, the "lone paren" is definitely better than the sole positive alternative, a lone backslash -- the latter's very fragile and picky in terms of placement, trailing space, etc, etc. The choice is _where_ to place that lone paren, and my preference is to have it at the point where, syntactically, a paren's needed anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have *anything*, even whitespace, after the line continuation character.

Either delete the whitespace, or wrap the entire line in a pair of parentheses.  [Python implicitly joins lines between parentheses, curly braces, and square brackets](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining):

```
print ( "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % 
        (i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying these lines:

```
        print "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % \         # mistake probably here
            (i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera)
```

to this line:

```
        print "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % (i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera)
```

Also, note that a line ending with a backslash cannot carry a comment. So your `#mistake probably here` comment is likely causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try rewriting this:

```
print "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % \         # mistake probably here
            (i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera)
```

To this:

```
print ("%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" %
       (i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera))
```

`\` should work too, but IMO it's less readable.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
print "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % \
    (i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera)
```

By:

```
print "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % (
    i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera)
```

General remark: always use English for identifiers

Comment: To the General who remarked this WHY always use English for identifiers ?

Comment: I personally agree about English, but the Python consensus does not: indeed, in Python 3 you're allowed to use non-ASCII alphamerics in identifiers, too, to make your identifiers "proper" non-English. I grumbled about it at the time but Guido was adamant!-)

Comment: @Blauchr, non-English identifiers limit you to sensibly discussing and sharing your code with a relatively tiny local community, English lets you easily cooperate (include meaningfully asking question and receiving advice) on a worldwide basis. I'm not a native speaker of English, but I can help people who use English identifiers much better than those who use Finnish, Mandarin, Arabic, Japanese, etc, etc -- and that's pretty common!-)

Answer (score 1):

In general, I find I don't use line continuation in Python.  You can make it cleaner with parentheses and so on.

Answer (score 0):

"\" means "this line continue to the next line" and it can't have any character after it. There probably is a space right after.

Two solution :

Ensure there is not spaces after;

Rewrite the statement on one line :

```
print "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % (i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera)
```

You can even use parenthesis to make it fit on several lines :

```
print "%2d. %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f" % (
       i, lyhennys, korkoera, kuukausiera)
```